# The LINQ expression node type 'ArrayIndex' is not supported in LINQ to Entities.

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

i have the folloiwng code inside my asp.net mvc application:-

```
    var result = from userContactInfo in entities.AaaUserContactInfoes
                 join contactInfo in entities.AaaContactInfoes on userContactInfo.CONTACTINFO_ID equals contactInfo.CONTACTINFO_ID

                                          where organizationNames.Any(orgName => contactInfo.EMAILID.Split('@')[1].Split('.')[0].Contains(orgName))
                 select userContactInfo;
```

But i am getting the following error:-

```
The LINQ expression node type 'ArrayIndex' is not supported in LINQ to Entities.
```

So what might be causing this error?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8353948/the-linq-expression-node-type-arrayindex-is-not-supported-in-linq-to-entities

Comment: yes this is the problem.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but i am not sure where i should apply PresId in my code??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated in the comments, you can't use an array when constructing an EF query. To solve this, I would recommend trying the following trickery in your where clause:

```
where organizationNames.Any(orgName => contactInfo.EMAILID.Contains("@" + orgName + "."))
```